# Why does AHRS system with Madgwick filter has so big drift?

Tags: pcb, imu, drift, mpu

I have an [MPU9250](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf) on my PCB and I use an AHRS system with a Madgwick filter to get yaw angles. I want to get very accurate and non-drifting yaw angles, but, for unknown reasons, I can't.

I calibrated the magnetometer, so I don't think that is the problem. The yaw angle drifts by about 10 degrees every 3 seconds. Here is the filter:

```c
void MadgwickAHRSupdate(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az, float mx, float my, float mz) {
    float recipNorm;
    float s0, s1, s2, s3;
    float qDot1, qDot2, qDot3, qDot4;
    float hx, hy;
    float _2q0mx, _2q0my, _2q0mz, _2q1mx, _2bx, _2bz, _4bx, _4bz, _2q0, _2q1, _2q2, _2q3, _2q0q2, _2q2q3, q0q0, q0q1, q0q2, q0q3, q1q1, q1q2, q1q3, q2q2, q2q3, q3q3;

    // Use IMU algorithm if magnetometer measurement invalid (avoids NaN in magnetometer normalisation)
    if((mx == 0.0f) && (my == 0.0f) && (mz == 0.0f)) {
        MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az);
        return;
    }

    // Rate of change of quaternion from gyroscope
    qDot1 = 0.5f * (-q1 * gx - q2 * gy - q3 * gz);
    qDot2 = 0.5f * (q0 * gx + q2 * gz - q3 * gy);
    qDot3 = 0.5f * (q0 * gy - q1 * gz + q3 * gx);
    qDot4 = 0.5f * (q0 * gz + q1 * gy - q2 * gx);

    // Compute feedback only if accelerometer measurement valid (avoids NaN in accelerometer normalisation)
    if(!((ax == 0.0f) && (ay == 0.0f) && (az == 0.0f))) {

        // Normalise accelerometer measurement
        recipNorm = invSqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
        ax *= recipNorm;
        ay *= recipNorm;
        az *= recipNorm;

        // Normalise magnetometer measurement
        recipNorm = invSqrt(mx * mx + my * my + mz * mz);
        mx *= recipNorm;
        my *= recipNorm;
        mz *= recipNorm;

        // Auxiliary variables to avoid repeated arithmetic
        _2q0mx = 2.0f * q0 * mx;
        _2q0my = 2.0f * q0 * my;
        _2q0mz = 2.0f * q0 * mz;
        _2q1mx = 2.0f * q1 * mx;
        _2q0 = 2.0f * q0;
        _2q1 = 2.0f * q1;
        _2q2 = 2.0f * q2;
        _2q3 = 2.0f * q3;
        _2q0q2 = 2.0f * q0 * q2;
        _2q2q3 = 2.0f * q2 * q3;
        q0q0 = q0 * q0;
        q0q1 = q0 * q1;
        q0q2 = q0 * q2;
        q0q3 = q0 * q3;
        q1q1 = q1 * q1;
        q1q2 = q1 * q2;
        q1q3 = q1 * q3;
        q2q2 = q2 * q2;
        q2q3 = q2 * q3;
        q3q3 = q3 * q3;

        // Reference direction of Earth's magnetic field
        hx = mx * q0q0 - _2q0my * q3 + _2q0mz * q2 + mx * q1q1 + _2q1 * my * q2 + _2q1 * mz * q3 - mx * q2q2 - mx * q3q3;
        hy = _2q0mx * q3 + my * q0q0 - _2q0mz * q1 + _2q1mx * q2 - my * q1q1 + my * q2q2 + _2q2 * mz * q3 - my * q3q3;
        _2bx = sqrt(hx * hx + hy * hy);
        _2bz = -_2q0mx * q2 + _2q0my * q1 + mz * q0q0 + _2q1mx * q3 - mz * q1q1 + _2q2 * my * q3 - mz * q2q2 + mz * q3q3;
        _4bx = 2.0f * _2bx;
        _4bz = 2.0f * _2bz;

        // Gradient decent algorithm corrective step
        s0 = -_2q2 * (2.0f * q1q3 - _2q0q2 - ax) + _2q1 * (2.0f * q0q1 + _2q2q3 - ay) - _2bz * q2 * (_2bx * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) + _2bz * (q1q3 - q0q2) - mx) + (-_2bx * q3 + _2bz * q1) * (_2bx * (q1q2 - q0q3) + _2bz * (q0q1 + q2q3) - my) + _2bx * q2 * (_2bx * (q0q2 + q1q3) + _2bz * (0.5f - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
        s1 = _2q3 * (2.0f * q1q3 - _2q0q2 - ax) + _2q0 * (2.0f * q0q1 + _2q2q3 - ay) - 4.0f * q1 * (1 - 2.0f * q1q1 - 2.0f * q2q2 - az) + _2bz * q3 * (_2bx * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) + _2bz * (q1q3 - q0q2) - mx) + (_2bx * q2 + _2bz * q0) * (_2bx * (q1q2 - q0q3) + _2bz * (q0q1 + q2q3) - my) + (_2bx * q3 - _4bz * q1) * (_2bx * (q0q2 + q1q3) + _2bz * (0.5f - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
        s2 = -_2q0 * (2.0f * q1q3 - _2q0q2 - ax) + _2q3 * (2.0f * q0q1 + _2q2q3 - ay) - 4.0f * q2 * (1 - 2.0f * q1q1 - 2.0f * q2q2 - az) + (-_4bx * q2 - _2bz * q0) * (_2bx * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) + _2bz * (q1q3 - q0q2) - mx) + (_2bx * q1 + _2bz * q3) * (_2bx * (q1q2 - q0q3) + _2bz * (q0q1 + q2q3) - my) + (_2bx * q0 - _4bz * q2) * (_2bx * (q0q2 + q1q3) + _2bz * (0.5f - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
        s3 = _2q1 * (2.0f * q1q3 - _2q0q2 - ax) + _2q2 * (2.0f * q0q1 + _2q2q3 - ay) + (-_4bx * q3 + _2bz * q1) * (_2bx * (0.5f - q2q2 - q3q3) + _2bz * (q1q3 - q0q2) - mx) + (-_2bx * q0 + _2bz * q2) * (_2bx * (q1q2 - q0q3) + _2bz * (q0q1 + q2q3) - my) + _2bx * q1 * (_2bx * (q0q2 + q1q3) + _2bz * (0.5f - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
        recipNorm = invSqrt(s0 * s0 + s1 * s1 + s2 * s2 + s3 * s3); // normalise step magnitude
        s0 *= recipNorm;
        s1 *= recipNorm;
        s2 *= recipNorm;
        s3 *= recipNorm;

        // Apply feedback step
        qDot1 -= beta * s0;
        qDot2 -= beta * s1;
        qDot3 -= beta * s2;
        qDot4 -= beta * s3;
    }

    // Integrate rate of change of quaternion to yield quaternion
    q0 += qDot1 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q1 += qDot2 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q2 += qDot3 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q3 += qDot4 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);

    // Normalise quaternion
    recipNorm = invSqrt(q0 * q0 + q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3);
    q0 *= recipNorm;
    q1 *= recipNorm;
    q2 *= recipNorm;
    q3 *= recipNorm;
}
```

This is how I use the filter:

```c
void Process_IMU()
{
    //read raw data
    uint8_t data[14];
    uint8_t reg = ACCEL_XOUT_H;
    uint8_t mpu_address = MPU9250_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;


    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(_MPU9250_I2C,(uint16_t)mpu_address,&reg,1,1000) != HAL_OK);
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(_MPU9250_I2C, (uint16_t)mpu_address, data, 14, 1000) != HAL_OK);

    /*-------- Accel ---------*/
    Accel_x = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[0] << 8 ) | data[1]);
    Accel_y = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[2] << 8 ) | data[3]);
    Accel_z = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[4] << 8 ) | data[5]);

    /*-------- Gyrometer --------*/
    Gyro_x = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[8] << 8  ) | data[9]);
    Gyro_y = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[10] << 8 ) | data[11]);
    Gyro_z = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[12] << 8 ) | data[13]);


    Accel_X = 10.0*(float)((int32_t)Accel_x - Accel_x_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;
    Accel_Y = 10.0*(float)((int32_t)Accel_y - Accel_y_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;
    Accel_Z = 10.0*(float)((int32_t)Accel_z - Accel_z_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;

    Gyro_X =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_x - Gyro_x_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0f;
    Gyro_Y =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_y - Gyro_y_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0f;
    Gyro_Z =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_z - Gyro_z_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0f;

    // Get data of Magnetometer
    Get_magnetometer();

    MadgwickAHRSupdate(Gyro_X,Gyro_Y,Gyro_Z,Accel_X,Accel_Y,Accel_Z,Mag_Y_calib,Mag_X_calib,-Mag_Z_calib);
}
```

The `Get_magnetometer` function:

```c
void Get_magnetometer()
{
    uint8_t raw_data[7];
    uint8_t reg_ST1 = ST1;
    uint8_t mag_address = MAG_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;
    uint8_t reg = XOUT_L;
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(_MPU9250_I2C,(uint16_t)mag_address,&reg_ST1,1,1000) != HAL_OK);
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(_MPU9250_I2C,(uint16_t)mag_address,raw_data,1,1000) != HAL_OK);
    if (raw_data[0] & 0x01)
    {
        while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(_MPU9250_I2C,(uint16_t)mag_address,&reg,1,1000) != HAL_OK);
        while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(_MPU9250_I2C,(uint16_t)mag_address,raw_data,7,1000) != HAL_OK);
        // Read the six raw data and ST2 registers sequentially into data arra
        if(!(raw_data[6] & 0x08))// Check if magnetic sensor overflow set, if not then report data
        {
            Mag_x = (int16_t)((raw_data[1]<<8) | raw_data[0] );
            Mag_y = (int16_t)((raw_data[3]<<8) | raw_data[2] );
            Mag_z = (int16_t)((raw_data[5]<<8) | raw_data[4] );
        }


        Mag_X_calib = (float)Mag_x * asax * mag_sensitivity - mag_offset[0];
        Mag_Y_calib = (float)Mag_y * asay * mag_sensitivity - mag_offset[1];
        Mag_Z_calib = (float)Mag_z * asaz * mag_sensitivity - mag_offset[2];

        Mag_X_calib *=scale_x;
        Mag_Y_calib *=scale_y;
        Mag_Z_calib *=scale_z;

    }
}
```

This is how I calculate the Euler angles:

```c
 while (1)
  {
    Process_IMU();

    q[0] = q0;
    q[1] = q1;
    q[2] = q2;
    q[3] = q3;
    a12 =   2.0f * (q[1] * q[2] + q[0] * q[3]);
    a22 =   q[0] * q[0] + q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] - q[3] * q[3];
    a31 =   2.0f * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3]);
    a32 =   2.0f * (q[1] * q[3] - q[0] * q[2]);
    a33 =   q[0] * q[0] - q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3];
    float sinp = a32;
    if (abs(sinp) >= 1)
        pitch = copysign(M_PI/2,sinp);
    else
        pitch =  asin(sinp);
    //pitch = -asinf(a32);
    roll  = atan2f(a31, a33);
    yaw   = atan2f(a12, a22);
    pitch *= 180.0f / pi;
    yaw = atan2f(sinf(yaw),cosf(yaw));
    yaw   *= 180.0f / pi;
    roll  *= 180.0f / pi;

    HAL_Delay(10);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

This is how the yaw angle changes:

[image]

What could be the reason of this? What should I change or calibrate?
I took almost all the functions from here: https://github.com/sonphambk/MPU9250
**EDIT 1:** I rewrote a python library for *MPU9250* to C (the python library: https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py):

```c
void mulMat(double mat1[][C1], double mat2[][C2], double mat3[R1][C2]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < R1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C2; j++) {
            mat3[i][j] = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < R2; k++) {
                mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            }
         }
     }
}

void MadgwickAHRSupdatePy(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az, float mx, float my, float mz)
{
    float norm;

    // Use IMU algorithm if magnetometer measurement invalid (avoids NaN in magnetometer normalisation)
    if((mx == 0.0f) && (my == 0.0f) && (mz == 0.0f)) {
        MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az);
        return;
    }

    // Compute feedback only if accelerometer measurement valid (avoids NaN in accelerometer normalisation)
    if(!((ax == 0.0f) && (ay == 0.0f) && (az == 0.0f)) && !((mx == 0.0f) && (my == 0.0f) && (mz == 0.0f))) {
        norm = sqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
        ax /= norm;
        ay /= norm;
        az /= norm;

        norm = sqrt(mx * mx + my * my + mz * mz);
        mx /= norm;
        my /= norm;
        mz /= norm;

        Quaternion h, qConj, qMag;
        Quaternion_set(0, mx, my, mz, &qMag);
        Quaternion_conjugate(&selfQ, &qConj);

        Quaternion_multiply(&qMag, &qConj, &h);
        Quaternion_multiply(&selfQ, &h, &h);

        double b[4] = {0, sqrt(h.v[0] * h.v[0] + h.v[1] * h.v[1]), 0, h.v[2]};
        double q_ins[4] = {selfQ.w, selfQ.v[0], selfQ.v[1], selfQ.v[2]};

        double f[1][6] = {{
                2 * (q_ins[1] * q_ins[3] - q_ins[0] * q_ins[2]) - ax,
                2 * (q_ins[0] * q_ins[1] + q_ins[2] * q_ins[3]) - ay,
                2 * (0.5 - q_ins[1] * q_ins[1] - q_ins[2] * q_ins[2]) - az,
                2 * b[1] * (0.5 - q_ins[2] * q_ins[2] - q_ins[3] * q_ins[3]) + 2 * b[3] * (q_ins[1] * q_ins[3] - q_ins[0] * q_ins[2]) - mx,
                2 * b[1] * (q_ins[1] * q_ins[2] - q_ins[0] * q_ins[3]) + 2 * b[3] * (q_ins[0] * q_ins[1] + q_ins[2] * q_ins[3]) - my,
                2 * b[1] * (q_ins[0] * q_ins[2] + q_ins[1] * q_ins[3]) + 2 * b[3] * (0.5 - q_ins[1] * q_ins[1] - q_ins[2] * q_ins[2]) - mz
        }};
        double j[6][4] = {
                {-2 * q_ins[2], 2 * q_ins[3], -2 * q_ins[0], 2 * q_ins[1]},
                {2 * q_ins[1], 2 * q_ins[0], 2 * q_ins[3], 2 * q_ins[2]},
                {0, -4 * q_ins[1], -4 * q_ins[2], 0},
                {-2 * b[3] * q_ins[2], 2 * b[3] * q_ins[3], -4 * b[1] * q_ins[2] - 2 * b[3] * q_ins[0], -4 * b[1] * q_ins[3] + 2 * b[3] * q_ins[1]},
                {-2 * b[1] * q_ins[3] + 2 * b[3] * q_ins[1], 2 * b[1] * q_ins[2] + 2 * b[3] * q_ins[0], 2 * b[1] * q_ins[1] + 2 * b[3] * q_ins[3],  -2 * b[1] * q_ins[0] + 2 * b[3] * q_ins[2]},
                {2 * b[1] * q_ins[2], 2 * b[1] * q_ins[3] - 4 * b[3] * q_ins[1], 2 * b[1] * q_ins[0] - 4 * b[3] * q_ins[2],  2 * b[1] * q_ins[1]}
        };
        double step2d[1][4];
        mulMat(f, j, step2d);

        double s1 = step2d[0][0];
        double s2 = step2d[0][1];
        double s3 = step2d[0][2];
        double s4 = step2d[0][3];
        norm = sqrt(s1 * s1 + s2 * s2 + s3 * s3 + s4 * s4);
        s1 /= norm;
        s2 /= norm;
        s3 /= norm;
        s4 /= norm;

        Quaternion qGyro;
        Quaternion_set(0, gx, gy, gz, &qGyro);

        Quaternion_multiply(&qGyro, &selfQ, &h);
        double qDot1 = (h.w * 0.5 - beta * s1) * (1 / sampleFreq);
        double qDot2 = (h.v[0] * 0.5 - beta * s2) * (1 / sampleFreq);
        double qDot3 = (h.v[1] * 0.5 - beta * s3) * (1 / sampleFreq);
        double qDot4 = (h.v[2] * 0.5 - beta * s4) * (1 / sampleFreq);

        q_ins[0] += qDot1;
        q_ins[1] += qDot2;
        q_ins[2] += qDot3;
        q_ins[3] += qDot4;

        norm = sqrt(q_ins[0] * q_ins[0] + q_ins[1] * q_ins[1] + q_ins[2] * q_ins[2] + q_ins[3] * q_ins[3]);
        q_ins[0] /= norm;
        q_ins[1] /= norm;
        q_ins[2] /= norm;
        q_ins[3] /= norm;

        q0 = q_ins[0];
        q1 = q_ins[1];
        q2 = q_ins[2];
        q3 = q_ins[3];

        Quaternion_set(q_ins[0], q_ins[1], q_ins[2], q_ins[3], &selfQ);
    }


}
```

But the result is the same. The *yaw* angle goes away very fast.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the original code? The another fact difficult to understand is that you copy already existent optimized values q0, q1,...to an array, then using a hardcoded index. Did you ever try to disassemble the resultant machine code? I guess no, because you would probably avoid adding this useless overhead.

Comment: Did you take into account that embedded sensors may have different coordinate system orientation? [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLT6l.png) [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @MarkoBuršič uh, sorry. I did this because I wanted to debug the code, I know that I shouldn't do this, but it is just for debug. With the original code results are the same.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Re: "Did you take into account that embedded sensors may have different coordinate system orientation?" Yes, as you can see here ```MadgwickAHRSupdate(Gyro_X,Gyro_Y,Gyro_Z,Accel_X,Accel_Y,Accel_Z,Mag_Y_calib,Mag_X_calib,-Mag_Z_calib);``` [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: But you also have some mistakes: 1.) 10*(float)((int32_t)Accel_x - Accel_x_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity; - 10.0 not 10, if you use fixed gain aka sensitvity, you should multiply there, you do spare 1 float MUL operation. The same for others: *M_PI/180.0f;  2nd mistake: the AHRS update shall be called at deterministic time....and so on. Try to run without calib values, use raw instead. This version is obsolete, there is a new version of Magdwick alsorithm.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thanks for reply. But I did as you say and it didn't help. And where can I find a new version of the algorithm?

Comment: The first thing to try is to feed hardcoded static data and see what happens. The second thing, perhaps to check this is not related due to rounding error. Check IMU little/big-endian. Your variable declaration is missing.

Comment: "while(1){}" loop cycles longer than "HAL_Delay(10)".

Comment: Have you solved the problem? @MarkoBuršič pointed out, the sampling time is not "10 x". You have more than HAL_Delay(10). And the excess accumulates over time, thus it drifts.

Comment: @jay I took all the code from here: https://github.com/sonphambk/MPU9250/tree/master/Src and in my code I tried different delays - but result was the same. And when I try to solve this problem - another problem appears - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70242354/why-does-yaw-angle-goes-away-when-i-move-controller. So I don't have solution now